# function IBuilder::buildEngineWithConfig() returns null

Tags: deep-learning, tensorrt

I am using tensorRT to build a small model as below:

```
#include "NvInfer.h"
#include "cuda_runtime_api.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include "include/Utils.h"
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include "src/InferDeleter.cpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace nvinfer1;

class MyLogger : public ILogger {
    void log(Severity severity, const char *msg) override {
        if (severity != Severity::kINFO) {
            cout << msg << endl;
        }
    }
} gLogger;

int main() {
    //load weights
    map<string, Weights> mWeightMap = Utils::getInstance().loadWeights("Weights/mnistapi.wts");
    //a few configuration parameters
    const char *INPUT_BLOB_NAME = "input";
    const char *OUTPUT_BLOB_NAME = "output";
    DataType dataType = nvinfer1::DataType::kFLOAT;
    int INPUT_H = 28, INPUT_W = 28;
    int batchSize = 1;
    //define the network
    IBuilder *builder = createInferBuilder(gLogger);

    INetworkDefinition *network = builder->createNetworkV2(0U);

    // Create input tensor of shape { 1, 1, 28, 28 }
    ITensor *data = network->addInput(
            INPUT_BLOB_NAME, DataType::kFLOAT, Dims3{1, INPUT_H, INPUT_W});
    // Create scale layer with default power/shift and specified scale parameter.
    const float scaleParam = 0.0125f;
    const Weights power{DataType::kFLOAT, nullptr, 0};
    const Weights shift{DataType::kFLOAT, nullptr, 0};
    const Weights scale{DataType::kFLOAT, &scaleParam, 1};
    IScaleLayer *scale_1 = network->addScale(*data, ScaleMode::kUNIFORM, shift, scale, power);
    // Add convolution layer with 20 outputs and a 5x5 filter.
    IConvolutionLayer *conv1 = network->addConvolutionNd(
            *scale_1->getOutput(0), 20, Dims{2, {5, 5}, {}}, mWeightMap["conv1filter"], mWeightMap["conv1bias"]);
    conv1->setStride(DimsHW{1, 1});
   
    // Add max pooling layer with stride of 2x2 and kernel size of 2x2.
    IPoolingLayer *pool1 = network->addPoolingNd(*conv1->getOutput(0), PoolingType::kMAX, Dims{2, {2, 2}, {}});
    pool1->setStride(DimsHW{2, 2});
  
    // Add second convolution layer with 50 outputs and a 5x5 filter.
    IConvolutionLayer *conv2 = network->addConvolutionNd(
            *pool1->getOutput(0), 50, Dims{2, {5, 5}, {}}, mWeightMap["conv2filter"], mWeightMap["conv2bias"]);
    conv2->setStride(DimsHW{1, 1});
 
    // Add second max pooling layer with stride of 2x2 and kernel size of 2x3>
    IPoolingLayer *pool2 = network->addPoolingNd(*conv2->getOutput(0), PoolingType::kMAX, Dims{2, {2, 2}, {}});
    pool2->setStride(DimsHW{2, 2});

    // Add fully connected layer with 500 outputs.
    IFullyConnectedLayer *ip1
            = network->addFullyConnected(*pool2->getOutput(0), 500, mWeightMap["ip1filter"], mWeightMap["ip1bias"]);

    // Add activation layer using the ReLU algorithm.
    IActivationLayer *relu1 = network->addActivation(*ip1->getOutput(0), ActivationType::kRELU);
    // Add second fully connected layer with 20 outputs.
 
    IFullyConnectedLayer *ip2 = network->addFullyConnected(
            *relu1->getOutput(0), 10, mWeightMap["ip2filter"], mWeightMap["ip2bias"]);
    // Add softmax layer to determine the probability.
   
    ISoftMaxLayer *prob = network->addSoftMax(*ip2->getOutput(0));
  
    prob->getOutput(0)->setName(OUTPUT_BLOB_NAME);
    network->markOutput(*prob->getOutput(0));
    //build engine

    IBuilderConfig *builderConfig = builder->createBuilderConfig();
    builder->setMaxBatchSize(batchSize);
    builderConfig->setMaxWorkspaceSize(1<<24);
    
    //engine null
    ICudaEngine *engine = builder->buildEngineWithConfig(*network, *builderConfig);
    //later uses of engine.
    return 0;
}
```

However, the function `builder->buildEngineWithConfig(*network, *builderConfig)` returns `nullptr`. I tried to change `maxWorkSpace` to other values but it still does not work. I also visited this [post](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/issues/782) but nothing help. Anyone points out the causes of the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of rolling over this problem. I have found that if layers in the model does not match the weight passed in, there is no error will appear but you can not create an TensorRT engine to do later tasks. Therefore, the best way to do in this situation is carefully checking layer by layer and the `.wts` file.